# JQuery, .attr - Remember state using cookies after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I wrote a function that changes logo to minimised version of it when I click on a button by changing attribute of an image. Also, after another click on the same button, logo switches back to original.

Everything is as I expected but I have a problem when I refresh the page. When I refresh the page, the browser just switches the logo back to original. So, I want the browser to remember if logo is switched and remember that state after reload of page. Please see my code below. I've seen similar solutions here but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

How can I set and use cookies for this?

```
$('#changeLogo').click(function() {
    if ($(".logo").attr('src') === "files/img/logo-min.png") {
        $(".logo").attr('src', "files/img/logo.png");
    }
    else {
        $(".logo").attr('src', "files/img/logo-min.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: why not use local storage instead?

Comment: Are you saying you googled how to use cookies and found nothing?

Comment: I did my research but couldn't find the way to get the right result. There is not a single example online about remembering state after using .attr() method. I know that is not that challenging but I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localstorage is a better option for this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#changeLogo').click(function() {
        var logoSrc;
        if ($(".logo").attr('src') === "files/img/logo-min.png") {
            logoSrc = "files/img/logo.png";
        }
        else {
            logoSrc = "files/img/logo-min.png";
        }

        $(".logo").attr('src', logoSrc);
        localStorage.setItem("logoSrc", logoSrc);
    });


    if ( typeof localStorage.logoSrc !== "undefined" )
        $(".logo").attr('src', localStorage.logoSrc);
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for this. It's perfect.

Comment: @SixthWiz Welcome to the community, you can accept an answer which completely solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var logo = localStorage.getItem('logo');
   if(logo != null){
    $(".logo").attr('src', logo);
   }
   $('#changeLogo').click(function() {
        if ($(".logo").attr('src') === "files/img/logo-min.png") {
            $(".logo").attr('src', "files/img/logo.png");
        }
        else {
            $(".logo").attr('src', "files/img/logo-min.png");
        }
        localStorage.setItem('logo',$(".logo").attr('src')); 
    });

});
```

Set src in localStorage and on page load get the value and set the src again to logo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use cookies, you can use the JQuery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Then :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (typeof $.cookie('logo') === 'undefined')
        $.cookie('logo', "files/img/logo-min.png");

    $('#changeLogo').click(function() {
        if ($.cookie('logo') === "files/img/logo-min.png") {
            $.cookie('logo', "files/img/logo.png");
        } else {
            $.cookie('logo', "files/img/logo-min.png");
        }
        $(".logo").attr('src', $.cookie('logo'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies using javascript api: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Or use an easier api like this: 
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

So in the `if/else` you can save the currently used link of the logo to a cookie:

```
//set
Cookies.set('logo-path', 'files/img/logo-min.png');
//get
Cookies.get('logo-path');
```

You could also utilize local storage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) but it is not guaranteed that it will work on older browsers.